# lvgl 8 on ESP32-S3 stucks in reboot loop

Tags: c++, esp32, esp-idf, lvgl

I try to use the current version of `lvgl` and `lvgl_esp32_drivers` on a custom ESP32-S3 board with esp-idf v5.0.1 with the following application:

```
static void guiTask(void* p_Args)
{
    static lv_disp_draw_buf_t draw_buf;
    static lv_color_t buf[480 * 10];

    lvgl_driver_init();

    lv_init();
    lv_disp_draw_buf_init(&draw_buf, buf, NULL, 480 * 10);

    /*Create a white label, set its text and align it to the center*/
    lv_obj_t * label = lv_label_create(lv_scr_act());
    lv_label_set_text(label, "Hello world");
    lv_obj_set_style_text_color(lv_scr_act(), lv_color_hex(0xffffff), LV_PART_MAIN);
    lv_obj_align(label, LV_ALIGN_CENTER, 0, 0);

    while(true)
    {
        lv_timer_handler();
        vTaskDelay(5 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}

extern "C" void app_main(void)
{
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(guiTask, "gui", 8192, NULL, 0, NULL, 1);
}
```

I have fixed several compile issues in `lvgl_esp32_drivers` to make it compatible with esp-idf v5 (mostly missing includes) and I use the following configuration for `lvgl`:

```
#
# LVGL configuration
#
CONFIG_LV_CONF_SKIP=y
# CONFIG_LV_CONF_MINIMAL is not set

#
# Color settings
#
# CONFIG_LV_COLOR_DEPTH_32 is not set
CONFIG_LV_COLOR_DEPTH_16=y
# CONFIG_LV_COLOR_DEPTH_8 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_COLOR_DEPTH_1 is not set
CONFIG_LV_COLOR_DEPTH=16
CONFIG_LV_COLOR_16_SWAP=y
# CONFIG_LV_COLOR_SCREEN_TRANSP is not set
CONFIG_LV_COLOR_MIX_ROUND_OFS=128
CONFIG_LV_COLOR_CHROMA_KEY_HEX=0x00FF00
# end of Color settings

#
# Memory settings
#
# CONFIG_LV_MEM_CUSTOM is not set
CONFIG_LV_MEM_SIZE_KILOBYTES=32
CONFIG_LV_MEM_ADDR=0x0
CONFIG_LV_MEM_BUF_MAX_NUM=16
CONFIG_LV_MEMCPY_MEMSET_STD=y
# end of Memory settings

#
# HAL Settings
#
CONFIG_LV_DISP_DEF_REFR_PERIOD=30
CONFIG_LV_INDEV_DEF_READ_PERIOD=30
# CONFIG_LV_TICK_CUSTOM is not set
CONFIG_LV_DPI_DEF=130
# end of HAL Settings

#
# Feature configuration
#

#
# Drawing
#
CONFIG_LV_DRAW_COMPLEX=y
CONFIG_LV_SHADOW_CACHE_SIZE=0
CONFIG_LV_CIRCLE_CACHE_SIZE=4
CONFIG_LV_LAYER_SIMPLE_BUF_SIZE=24576
CONFIG_LV_IMG_CACHE_DEF_SIZE=0
CONFIG_LV_GRADIENT_MAX_STOPS=2
CONFIG_LV_GRAD_CACHE_DEF_SIZE=0
# CONFIG_LV_DITHER_GRADIENT is not set
CONFIG_LV_DISP_ROT_MAX_BUF=10240
# end of Drawing

#
# GPU
#
# CONFIG_LV_USE_GPU_ARM2D is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_GPU_STM32_DMA2D is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_GPU_SWM341_DMA2D is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_GPU_NXP_PXP is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_GPU_NXP_VG_LITE is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_GPU_SDL is not set
# end of GPU

#
# Logging
#
# CONFIG_LV_USE_LOG is not set
# end of Logging

#
# Asserts
#
CONFIG_LV_USE_ASSERT_NULL=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_ASSERT_MALLOC=y
# CONFIG_LV_USE_ASSERT_STYLE is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_ASSERT_MEM_INTEGRITY is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_ASSERT_OBJ is not set
CONFIG_LV_ASSERT_HANDLER_INCLUDE="assert.h"
# end of Asserts

#
# Others
#
# CONFIG_LV_USE_PERF_MONITOR is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_MEM_MONITOR is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_REFR_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_LV_SPRINTF_CUSTOM is not set
# CONFIG_LV_SPRINTF_USE_FLOAT is not set
CONFIG_LV_USE_USER_DATA=y
# CONFIG_LV_ENABLE_GC is not set
# end of Others

#
# Compiler settings
#
# CONFIG_LV_BIG_ENDIAN_SYSTEM is not set
CONFIG_LV_ATTRIBUTE_MEM_ALIGN_SIZE=1
# CONFIG_LV_ATTRIBUTE_FAST_MEM_USE_IRAM is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_LARGE_COORD is not set
# end of Compiler settings
# end of Feature configuration

#
# Font usage
#

#
# Enable built-in fonts
#
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_8 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_10 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_12 is not set
CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_14=y
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_16 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_18 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_20 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_22 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_24 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_26 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_28 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_30 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_32 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_34 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_36 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_38 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_40 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_42 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_44 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_46 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_48 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_12_SUBPX is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_MONTSERRAT_28_COMPRESSED is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEJAVU_16_PERSIAN_HEBREW is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_SIMSUN_16_CJK is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_UNSCII_8 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_UNSCII_16 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_CUSTOM is not set
# end of Enable built-in fonts

# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_8 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_12 is not set
CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_14=y
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_16 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_18 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_20 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_22 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_24 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_26 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_28 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_30 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_32 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_34 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_36 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_38 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_40 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_42 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_44 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_46 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_48 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_12_SUBPX is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_MONTSERRAT_28_COMPRESSED is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_DEJAVU_16_PERSIAN_HEBREW is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_SIMSUN_16_CJK is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_UNSCII_8 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_DEFAULT_UNSCII_16 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_FONT_FMT_TXT_LARGE is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FONT_COMPRESSED is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FONT_SUBPX is not set
CONFIG_LV_USE_FONT_PLACEHOLDER=y
# end of Font usage

#
# Text Settings
#
CONFIG_LV_TXT_ENC_UTF8=y
# CONFIG_LV_TXT_ENC_ASCII is not set
CONFIG_LV_TXT_BREAK_CHARS=" ,.;:-_)]}"
CONFIG_LV_TXT_LINE_BREAK_LONG_LEN=0
CONFIG_LV_TXT_COLOR_CMD="#"
# CONFIG_LV_USE_BIDI is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_ARABIC_PERSIAN_CHARS is not set
# end of Text Settings

#
# Widget usage
#
CONFIG_LV_USE_ARC=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_BAR=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_BTN=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_BTNMATRIX=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_CANVAS=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_CHECKBOX=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_DROPDOWN=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_IMG=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_LABEL=y
CONFIG_LV_LABEL_TEXT_SELECTION=y
CONFIG_LV_LABEL_LONG_TXT_HINT=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_LINE=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_ROLLER=y
CONFIG_LV_ROLLER_INF_PAGES=7
CONFIG_LV_USE_SLIDER=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_SWITCH=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_TEXTAREA=y
CONFIG_LV_TEXTAREA_DEF_PWD_SHOW_TIME=1500
CONFIG_LV_USE_TABLE=y
# end of Widget usage

#
# Extra Widgets
#
CONFIG_LV_USE_ANIMIMG=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_CALENDAR=y
# CONFIG_LV_CALENDAR_WEEK_STARTS_MONDAY is not set
CONFIG_LV_USE_CALENDAR_HEADER_ARROW=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_CALENDAR_HEADER_DROPDOWN=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_CHART=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_COLORWHEEL=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_IMGBTN=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_KEYBOARD=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_LED=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_LIST=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_MENU=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_METER=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_MSGBOX=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_SPAN=y
CONFIG_LV_SPAN_SNIPPET_STACK_SIZE=64
CONFIG_LV_USE_SPINBOX=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_SPINNER=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_TABVIEW=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_TILEVIEW=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_WIN=y
# end of Extra Widgets

#
# Themes
#
CONFIG_LV_USE_THEME_DEFAULT=y
# CONFIG_LV_THEME_DEFAULT_DARK is not set
CONFIG_LV_THEME_DEFAULT_GROW=y
CONFIG_LV_THEME_DEFAULT_TRANSITION_TIME=80
CONFIG_LV_USE_THEME_BASIC=y
# CONFIG_LV_USE_THEME_MONO is not set
# end of Themes

#
# Layouts
#
CONFIG_LV_USE_FLEX=y
CONFIG_LV_USE_GRID=y
# end of Layouts

#
# 3rd Party Libraries
#
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FS_STDIO is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FS_POSIX is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FS_WIN32 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FS_FATFS is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_PNG is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_BMP is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_SJPG is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_GIF is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_QRCODE is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FREETYPE is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_RLOTTIE is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FFMPEG is not set
# end of 3rd Party Libraries

#
# Others
#
CONFIG_LV_USE_SNAPSHOT=y
# CONFIG_LV_USE_MONKEY is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_GRIDNAV is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_FRAGMENT is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_IMGFONT is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_MSG is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_IME_PINYIN is not set
# end of Others

#
# Examples
#
# CONFIG_LV_BUILD_EXAMPLES is not set
# end of Examples

#
# Demos
#
# CONFIG_LV_USE_DEMO_WIDGETS is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_DEMO_KEYPAD_AND_ENCODER is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_DEMO_BENCHMARK is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_DEMO_STRESS is not set
# CONFIG_LV_USE_DEMO_MUSIC is not set
# end of Demos
# end of LVGL configuration

#
# LVGL ESP Drivers
#

#
# LVGL TFT Display controller
#
CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_NONE=y
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_WROVER4 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_M5STACK is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_M5CORE2 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_M5STICK is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_M5STICKC is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_ERTFT0356 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_ADA_FEATHERWING is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_RPI_MPI3501 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_WEMOS_LOLIN is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_ATAG is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_RPI_RA8875 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_TTGO is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_TTGO_CAMERA_PLUS is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_DISPLAY_WT32_SC01 is not set
CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_CONTROLLER_ILI9341=y
CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_PROTOCOL_SPI=y
CONFIG_LV_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT=y
# CONFIG_LV_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED is not set
# CONFIG_LV_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE is not set
# CONFIG_LV_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED is not set
CONFIG_LV_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION=0
CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_PINS_NONE=y
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_PINS_38V4 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_PINS_30 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_PINS_38V1 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_PREDEFINED_PINS_TKOALA is not set
CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_ILI9341=y
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_ILI9481 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_ILI9486 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_ILI9488 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_ST7789 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_ST7796S is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_GC9A01 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_ST7735S is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_HX8357 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_SH1107 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_SSD1306 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_FT81X is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_IL3820 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_JD79653A is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_UC8151D is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_RA8875 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_ILI9163C is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_USER_CONTROLLER_PCD8544 is not set
CONFIG_CUSTOM_DISPLAY_BUFFER_SIZE=y
CONFIG_CUSTOM_DISPLAY_BUFFER_BYTES=1024
CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_SPI2_HOST=y
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_SPI3_HOST is not set
CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_SPI_TRANS_MODE_SIO=y
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_SPI_TRANS_MODE_DIO is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_SPI_TRANS_MODE_QIO is not set
CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_SPI_HALF_DUPLEX=y
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_DISPLAY_SPI_FULL_DUPLEX is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TFT_USE_CUSTOM_SPI_CLK_DIVIDER is not set
CONFIG_LV_TFT_CUSTOM_SPI_CLK_DIVIDER=2
# CONFIG_LV_INVERT_COLORS is not set

#
# Display Pin Assignments
#
CONFIG_LV_DISP_SPI_MOSI=6
# CONFIG_LV_DISPLAY_USE_SPI_MISO is not set
CONFIG_LV_DISP_SPI_CLK=5
CONFIG_LV_DISPLAY_USE_SPI_CS=y
CONFIG_LV_DISP_SPI_CS=16
CONFIG_LV_DISPLAY_USE_DC=y
CONFIG_LV_DISP_PIN_DC=7
CONFIG_LV_DISP_USE_RST=y
CONFIG_LV_DISP_PIN_RST=15
# end of Display Pin Assignments

CONFIG_LV_DISP_BACKLIGHT_OFF=y
# CONFIG_LV_DISP_BACKLIGHT_SWITCH is not set
# CONFIG_LV_DISP_BACKLIGHT_PWM is not set
CONFIG_LV_I2C_DISPLAY_PORT=0
# end of LVGL TFT Display controller

#
# LVGL Touch controller
#
CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER=0
CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER_NONE=y
# CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER_XPT2046 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER_FT6X06 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER_STMPE610 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER_ADCRAW is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER_FT81X is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER_RA8875 is not set
# CONFIG_LV_TOUCH_CONTROLLER_GT911 is not set
CONFIG_LV_I2C_TOUCH_PORT=0
# end of LVGL Touch controller
# end of LVGL ESP Drivers
# end of Component config

# Deprecated options for backward compatibility
# CONFIG_NO_BLOBS is not set
CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_NONE=y
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_ERROR is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_WARN is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_INFO is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL_VERBOSE is not set
CONFIG_LOG_BOOTLOADER_LEVEL=0
# CONFIG_APP_ROLLBACK_ENABLE is not set
# CONFIG_FLASH_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED is not set
CONFIG_MONITOR_BAUD=115200
CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_COMPILER_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_DEBUG=y
# CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_RELEASE is not set
# CONFIG_COMPILER_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL_RELEASE is not set
CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_ENABLED=y
# CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_SILENT is not set
# CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTIONS_DISABLED is not set
CONFIG_OPTIMIZATION_ASSERTION_LEVEL=2
# CONFIG_CXX_EXCEPTIONS is not set
CONFIG_STACK_CHECK_NONE=y
# CONFIG_STACK_CHECK_NORM is not set
# CONFIG_STACK_CHECK_STRONG is not set
# CONFIG_STACK_CHECK_ALL is not set
# CONFIG_WARN_WRITE_STRINGS is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32_APPTRACE_DEST_TRAX is not set
CONFIG_ESP32_APPTRACE_DEST_NONE=y
CONFIG_ESP32_APPTRACE_LOCK_ENABLE=y
# CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED is not set
CONFIG_NIMBLE_ENABLED=y
CONFIG_NIMBLE_MEM_ALLOC_MODE_INTERNAL=y
# CONFIG_NIMBLE_MEM_ALLOC_MODE_EXTERNAL is not set
# CONFIG_NIMBLE_MEM_ALLOC_MODE_DEFAULT is not set
CONFIG_NIMBLE_MAX_CONNECTIONS=3
CONFIG_NIMBLE_MAX_BONDS=3
CONFIG_NIMBLE_MAX_CCCDS=8
CONFIG_NIMBLE_L2CAP_COC_MAX_NUM=0
CONFIG_NIMBLE_PINNED_TO_CORE_0=y
# CONFIG_NIMBLE_PINNED_TO_CORE_1 is not set
CONFIG_NIMBLE_PINNED_TO_CORE=0
CONFIG_NIMBLE_TASK_STACK_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_BT_NIMBLE_TASK_STACK_SIZE=4096
CONFIG_NIMBLE_ROLE_CENTRAL=y
CONFIG_NIMBLE_ROLE_PERIPHERAL=y
CONFIG_NIMBLE_ROLE_BROADCASTER=y
CONFIG_NIMBLE_ROLE_OBSERVER=y
# CONFIG_NIMBLE_NVS_PERSIST is not set
CONFIG_NIMBLE_SM_LEGACY=y
CONFIG_NIMBLE_SM_SC=y
# CONFIG_NIMBLE_SM_SC_DEBUG_KEYS is not set
# CONFIG_NIMBLE_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_NIMBLE_SVC_GAP_DEVICE_NAME="thermal"
CONFIG_NIMBLE_GAP_DEVICE_NAME_MAX_LEN=31
CONFIG_NIMBLE_ATT_PREFERRED_MTU=256
CONFIG_NIMBLE_SVC_GAP_APPEARANCE=0
CONFIG_BT_NIMBLE_MSYS1_BLOCK_COUNT=12
CONFIG_NIMBLE_ACL_BUF_COUNT=24
CONFIG_NIMBLE_ACL_BUF_SIZE=255
CONFIG_NIMBLE_HCI_EVT_BUF_SIZE=70
CONFIG_NIMBLE_HCI_EVT_HI_BUF_COUNT=30
CONFIG_NIMBLE_HCI_EVT_LO_BUF_COUNT=8
# CONFIG_NIMBLE_HS_FLOW_CTRL is not set
CONFIG_NIMBLE_RPA_TIMEOUT=900
# CONFIG_NIMBLE_MESH is not set
CONFIG_NIMBLE_CRYPTO_STACK_MBEDTLS=y
# CONFIG_MCPWM_ISR_IN_IRAM is not set
# CONFIG_EVENT_LOOP_PROFILING is not set
CONFIG_POST_EVENTS_FROM_ISR=y
CONFIG_POST_EVENTS_FROM_IRAM_ISR=y
# CONFIG_OTA_ALLOW_HTTP is not set
CONFIG_ESP32S3_DEEP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_DELAY=2000
CONFIG_ESP32S3_RTC_CLK_SRC_INT_RC=y
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_RTC_CLK_SRC_EXT_CRYS is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_RTC_CLK_SRC_EXT_OSC is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_RTC_CLK_SRC_INT_8MD256 is not set
CONFIG_ESP32S3_RTC_CLK_CAL_CYCLES=1024
CONFIG_ESP32_PHY_CALIBRATION_AND_DATA_STORAGE=y
# CONFIG_ESP32_PHY_INIT_DATA_IN_PARTITION is not set
CONFIG_ESP32_PHY_MAX_WIFI_TX_POWER=20
CONFIG_ESP32_PHY_MAX_TX_POWER=20
CONFIG_REDUCE_PHY_TX_POWER=y
CONFIG_ESP32_REDUCE_PHY_TX_POWER=y
CONFIG_ESP_SYSTEM_PM_POWER_DOWN_CPU=y
CONFIG_ESP32S3_SPIRAM_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_PSRAM_CLK_IO=30
CONFIG_DEFAULT_PSRAM_CS_IO=26
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_DEFAULT_CPU_FREQ_80 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_DEFAULT_CPU_FREQ_160 is not set
CONFIG_ESP32S3_DEFAULT_CPU_FREQ_240=y
CONFIG_ESP32S3_DEFAULT_CPU_FREQ_MHZ=240
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EVENT_QUEUE_SIZE=32
CONFIG_SYSTEM_EVENT_TASK_STACK_SIZE=2304
CONFIG_MAIN_TASK_STACK_SIZE=3584
CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_DEFAULT=y
# CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_CUSTOM is not set
# CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_NONE is not set
# CONFIG_ESP_CONSOLE_UART_NONE is not set
CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART=y
CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_NUM=0
CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_BAUDRATE=115200
CONFIG_INT_WDT=y
CONFIG_INT_WDT_TIMEOUT_MS=300
CONFIG_INT_WDT_CHECK_CPU1=y
CONFIG_ESP_TASK_WDT=y
# CONFIG_TASK_WDT_PANIC is not set
CONFIG_TASK_WDT_TIMEOUT_S=5
CONFIG_TASK_WDT_CHECK_IDLE_TASK_CPU0=y
CONFIG_TASK_WDT_CHECK_IDLE_TASK_CPU1=y
CONFIG_ESP32_DEBUG_STUBS_ENABLE=y
CONFIG_ESP32S3_DEBUG_OCDAWARE=y
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET=y
CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET=y
CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET=y
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_7=y
CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_7=y
# CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_6 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_6 is not set
# CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_5 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_5 is not set
# CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_4 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_4 is not set
# CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_3 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_3 is not set
# CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_2 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_2 is not set
# CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_1 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_1 is not set
CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL=7
CONFIG_ESP32S3_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL=7
CONFIG_IPC_TASK_STACK_SIZE=1024
CONFIG_TIMER_TASK_STACK_SIZE=3584
CONFIG_SW_COEXIST_ENABLE=y
# CONFIG_ESP32_ENABLE_COREDUMP_TO_UART is not set
CONFIG_ESP32_ENABLE_COREDUMP_TO_NONE=y
CONFIG_TIMER_TASK_PRIORITY=1
CONFIG_TIMER_TASK_STACK_DEPTH=2048
CONFIG_TIMER_QUEUE_LENGTH=10
# CONFIG_ENABLE_STATIC_TASK_CLEAN_UP_HOOK is not set
# CONFIG_HAL_ASSERTION_SILIENT is not set
# CONFIG_L2_TO_L3_COPY is not set
CONFIG_ESP_GRATUITOUS_ARP=y
CONFIG_GARP_TMR_INTERVAL=60
CONFIG_TCPIP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=32
CONFIG_TCP_MAXRTX=12
CONFIG_TCP_SYNMAXRTX=6
CONFIG_TCP_MSS=1440
CONFIG_TCP_MSL=60000
CONFIG_TCP_SND_BUF_DEFAULT=5744
CONFIG_TCP_WND_DEFAULT=5744
CONFIG_TCP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=6
CONFIG_TCP_QUEUE_OOSEQ=y
CONFIG_TCP_OVERSIZE_MSS=y
# CONFIG_TCP_OVERSIZE_QUARTER_MSS is not set
# CONFIG_TCP_OVERSIZE_DISABLE is not set
CONFIG_UDP_RECVMBOX_SIZE=6
CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_STACK_SIZE=3072
CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY_NO_AFFINITY=y
# CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY_CPU0 is not set
# CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY_CPU1 is not set
CONFIG_TCPIP_TASK_AFFINITY=0x7FFFFFFF
# CONFIG_PPP_SUPPORT is not set
CONFIG_ESP32S3_TIME_SYSCALL_USE_RTC_SYSTIMER=y
CONFIG_ESP32S3_TIME_SYSCALL_USE_RTC_FRC1=y
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_TIME_SYSCALL_USE_RTC is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_TIME_SYSCALL_USE_SYSTIMER is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_TIME_SYSCALL_USE_FRC1 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32S3_TIME_SYSCALL_USE_NONE is not set
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_TASK_PRIO_DEFAULT=5
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_TASK_STACK_SIZE_DEFAULT=3072
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_STACK_MIN=768
CONFIG_ESP32_DEFAULT_PTHREAD_CORE_NO_AFFINITY=y
# CONFIG_ESP32_DEFAULT_PTHREAD_CORE_0 is not set
# CONFIG_ESP32_DEFAULT_PTHREAD_CORE_1 is not set
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_TASK_CORE_DEFAULT=-1
CONFIG_ESP32_PTHREAD_TASK_NAME_DEFAULT="pthread"
CONFIG_SPI_FLASH_WRITING_DANGEROUS_REGIONS_ABORTS=y
# CONFIG_SPI_FLASH_WRITING_DANGEROUS_REGIONS_FAILS is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_FLASH_WRITING_DANGEROUS_REGIONS_ALLOWED is not set
CONFIG_SUPPRESS_SELECT_DEBUG_OUTPUT=y
CONFIG_SUPPORT_TERMIOS=y
CONFIG_SEMIHOSTFS_MAX_MOUNT_POINTS=1
# End of deprecated options
```

But the ESP s rebooting all the time:

```
ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x3 (RTC_SW_SYS_RST),boot:0x18 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40379c5a
SPIWP:0xee
Octal Flash Mode Enabled
For OPI Flash, Use Default Flash Boot Mode
mode:SLOW_RD, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3810,len:0x3b8
load:0x403c9700,len:0x9b4
load:0x403cc700,len:0x2710
entry 0x403c9868
I (118) octal_psram: vendor id    : 0x0d (AP)
I (118) octal_psram: dev id       : 0x02 (generation 3)
I (118) octal_psram: density      : 0x03 (64 Mbit)
I (123) octal_psram: good-die     : 0x01 (Pass)
I (128) octal_psram: Latency      : 0x01 (Fixed)
I (133) octal_psram: VCC          : 0x00 (1.8V)
I (139) octal_psram: SRF          : 0x01 (Fast Refresh)
I (145) octal_psram: BurstType    : 0x01 (Hybrid Wrap)
I (150) octal_psram: BurstLen     : 0x01 (32 Byte)
I (156) octal_psram: Readlatency  : 0x02 (10 cycles@Fixed)
I (162) octal_psram: DriveStrength: 0x00 (1/1)
I (167) esp_psram: Found 8MB PSRAM device
I (172) esp_psram: Speed: 40MHz
I (176) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.
I (179) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x40376644
I (0) cpu_start: App cpu up.
I (917) esp_psram: SPI SRAM memory test OK
I (925) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (926) cpu_start: cpu freq: 240000000 Hz
I (926) cpu_start: Application information:
I (929) cpu_start: Project name:     Lepton
I (933) cpu_start: App version:      1.0.0
I (938) cpu_start: Compile time:     May  4 2023 06:06:58
I (944) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  ca64ef3cc78c8853...
I (950) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          5.0.1
I (955) cpu_start: Min chip rev:     v0.0
I (960) cpu_start: Max chip rev:     v0.99 
I (965) cpu_start: Chip rev:         v0.1
I (969) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (977) heap_init: At 3FCA2140 len 000475D0 (285 KiB): D/IRAM
I (983) heap_init: At 3FCE9710 len 00005724 (21 KiB): STACK/DRAM
I (990) heap_init: At 3FCF0000 len 00008000 (32 KiB): DRAM
I (996) heap_init: At 600FE010 len 00001FF0 (7 KiB): RTCRAM
I (1002) esp_psram: Adding pool of 8192K of PSRAM memory to heap allocator
I (1010) spi_flash: detected chip: mxic (opi)
I (1015) spi_flash: flash io: opi_str
I (1019) coexist: coexist rom version e7ae62f
I (1024) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
I (1045) esp_psram: Reserving pool of 32K of internal memory for DMA/internal allocations
I (1065) lvgl_helpers: Display buffer size: 1024
I (1065) lvgl_helpers: Initializing SPI master for display
I (1065) lvgl_helpers: Configuring SPI host SPI2_HOST
I (1075) lvgl_helpers: MISO pin: -1, MOSI pin: 6, SCLK pin: 5, IO2/WP pin: -1, IO3/HD pin: -1
I (1085) lvgl_helpers: Max transfer size: 2048 (bytes)
I (1085) lvgl_helpers: Initializing SPI bus...
I (1095) disp_spi: Adding SPI device
I (1105) disp_spi: Clock speed: 40000000Hz, mode: 0, CS pin: 16
I (1325) ILI9341: Initialization.
I (1545) ILI9341: Display orientation: PORTRAIT
I (1545) ILI9341: 0x36 command value: 0x48
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x42003611  PS      : 0x00060c30  A0      : 0x82002eed  A1      : 0x3fceb890  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x0000004c  A5      : 0x3fc9936c
A6      : 0x00000010  A7      : 0x00000004  A8      : 0x3fca0ddc  A9      : 0x3fceb870
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x3fc99318  A12     : 0x0000004c  A13     : 0x3fc992cc  
A14     : 0x3c030368  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x00000003  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x00000022  LBEG    : 0x400570e8  LEND    : 0x400570f3  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x4200360e:0x3fceb890 0x42002eea:0x3fceb8b0 0x4200a9a3:0x3fceb8d0 0x420016e1:0x3fceb8f0 0x4037e54d:0x3fceb910

  #0  0x4200360e:0x3fceb890 in lv_obj_mark_layout_as_dirty at components\lvgl\src\core/lv_obj_pos.c:289
  #1  0x42002eea:0x3fceb8b0 in lv_obj_class_init_obj at components\lvgl\src\core/lv_obj_class.c:106
  #2  0x4200a9a3:0x3fceb8d0 in lv_label_create at components\lvgl\src\widgets/lv_label.c:77
  #3  0x420016e1:0x3fceb8f0 in guiTask(void*) at src/main.cpp:39
  #4  0x4037e54d:0x3fceb910 in vPortTaskWrapper at C:\Users\konta\.platformio\packages\framework-espidf\components\freertos\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\xtensa/port.c:154




ELF file SHA256: ca64ef3cc78c8853
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `lv_tick_inc` for example with a timer
and you are also missing the mechanics to actually update the tft-screen (you need to implement or have a defined `disp_driver_flush`

````
    lv_disp_drv_t disp_drv;
    lv_disp_drv_init(&disp_drv);
    disp_drv.flush_cb = disp_driver_flush;

    disp_drv.draw_buf = &disp_buf;
    lv_disp_drv_register(&disp_drv);


```
````